# How do i get my Windows Azure Worker Role to connect to my Ado.NEt Entity-based db

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, azure, azure-worker-roles

I've built a backend in ASP.NET MVC2 which has an underlying ADO.NET Entity-based Database.

In the MVC Backend, I call my database entities, i.e.:

```
Entities entities = new Entities();
```

...and that all works fine.

Unforutnetly, in my Azure/mvc2 project, My worker role makes the azure project throw weird exceptions:

```
"The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid."
```

Any ideas ladies and gentlemen?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself - it was a PEBKAC issue.
Had to manually set the configuration string in the Worker role's App.config (Copypasted from from the ASP/NET MVC2 Project's Web.config).

All works well now.